# Exit from the window I created

Tags: python, tkinter

I've written this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
```

How can I exit the window?

Comment: have you tried `root.destroy()`?

Comment: Well, I couldn't close the window so I couldn't execute commands.
Anyway I just had to press Alt+F4...